# Monitoring environment of applications running on cloud foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa, cf-bosh

Under the  `env:` block within `manifest.yml`, we mention artifact versions being run on app, before pushing the app(`cf push`) using `manifest.yml`

This will help cf user to get the artifact versions running on any app on cloud foundry using `cf env <app_name>` for each app.

---

For all apps running in cloudfoundry,  Can [firehose](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/loggregator/architecture.html#firehose) help us provide environment (`cf env`) data for each app?

Answer (score 1):

> For all apps running in cloudfoundry, Can firehose help us provide environment (cf env) data for each app?

It's unnecessary to listen to the firehose. Your app running on CF will have access to any environment variables that you set (i.e. that are visible with `cf env`) by simply using their language/runtime's ability to read an environment variable.

For example:

1. I run `cf set-env my-cool-app VERSION '1.0.0'`.
2. In my app, I can read `VERSION` to retrieve the value `1.0.0`.

In Java, you'd use `System.getenv("VERSION")`. In Node you'd use `process.env.VERSION`. In Python you'd use `os.environ['VERSION']`. etc...

Comment: I understand that... app running on CF has access to any environment variable... but as part of devops team, monitoring those apps, we want to read those values from outside thevapp

Comment: Then you run `cf env` or the direct API call. The only thing that shows up in the loggregator stream are metrics & log entries. I suppose you could have your app read the env variable and write it to loggregator (just write to STDOUT) but that seems like a lot of work. It's really hard for me to give more advise because I have no idea what your use case or motivations are here. Sorry.

Comment: we want to get the environment output of all apps running in multiple API end points, in single UI.... this our use case in devops team

Comment: Then you will want to use the cf cli or more probably the API directly, http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/.